# How to list procedures with CBAC privileges

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking at a set of build scripts for a Oracle 12c database that has stored procedures with Code Based Access Control.
I want to write a pre-deploy and post-deploy report to check the deployment has worked.

I would like to report on which procedures have CBAC privs. There must be  database dictionary view that has this but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is new in 12c onwards.

See `DBA_CODE_ROLE_PRIVS` (or ALL_ or USER_ if you dont have DBA level access).

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now. Thanks.